# Nearest non-NA value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, zoo

I have a dataframe `test`

```
> test
   foo  bar  baz  timestamp
1    1 <NA>    a 1552157998
2    1 <NA> <NA> 1552161596
3    1 stop <NA> 1552165194
4    1 <NA>    b 1552168795
5    1 <NA>    a 1552170839
6    1 <NA> <NA> 1552157998
7    1 stop <NA> 1552161596
8    1 <NA>    a 1552165194
9    1 <NA>    b 1552168795
10   1 <NA> <NA> 1552170839
```

My goal is to find, for each instance of `stop`, the nearest non-NA value in each direction (based on `timestamp`), which would produce a table such like this:

```
> output
  rownum pre post
1      3   a    b
2      7   a    a
```

Is there a known way to do this with `zoo` and `na.locf()` ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
dput(test)
structure(list(foo = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), bar = c(NA, 
NA, "stop", NA, NA, NA, "stop", NA, NA, NA), baz = c("a", NA, 
NA, "b", "a", NA, NA, "a", "b", NA), timestamp = c(1552157998.427, 
1552161596.004, 1552165194.255, 1552168794.918, 1552170839.363, 
1552157998.427, 1552161596.004, 1552165194.255, 1552168794.918, 
1552170839.363)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please include the `timestamp` column in your `dput`?

Comment: yes I have done so- edited

Comment: Does the subsequent elements use the same pre/post?

Comment: @akrun yes the same

Comment: I think you have your expected `pre` and `post` labels backwards.

Comment: Since you mentioned 'based on timestamp': Is the dataset supposed to be ordered before determining the next/previous element. Because I get a different result if this is the case

Comment: @r2evans yes I fixed that thanks

Comment: @Julian_Hn yes it should be ordered by timestamp

Comment: Perhaps `i1 <- which(test$bar == "stop");i2 <- which(!is.na(test$baz));i3 <- which(rev(!is.na(test$baz))); test$baz[i2][findInterval(i1, i2)]; rev(test$baz)[i3][findInterval(i1, i3)]`

Comment: @the_darkside Then your expected output is not correct. See the discussion on the answer by r2evans.

Comment: the_darkside, does my answer address your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use `magrittr` solely for organizing the code. This can be translated just as easily to non-`magrittr`, `dplyr`, or `data.table` with minimal effort.

```r
library(magrittr)
test %>%
  .[ order(.$timestamp), ] %>%
  transform(.,
            rownum = seq_len(nrow(.)),
            pre = zoo::na.locf0(baz),
            post = zoo::na.locf0(baz, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
  subset(., bar == "stop") %>%
  .[, c("rownum", "pre", "post")]
#   rownum pre post
# 7      4   a    a
# 3      5   a    a
```

(This is different than the expected output, possibly because that's a mistake?)

You can see a little bit better what this is doing by looking at it before `subset`:

```r
test %>%
  .[ order(.$timestamp), ] %>%
  transform(.,
            rownum = seq_len(nrow(.)),
            pre = zoo::na.locf0(baz),
            post = zoo::na.locf0(baz, fromLast = TRUE))
#    foo  bar  baz  timestamp rownum pre post
# 1    1 <NA>    a 1552157998      1   a    a
# 6    1 <NA> <NA> 1552157998      2   a    a
# 2    1 <NA> <NA> 1552161596      3   a    a
# 7    1 stop <NA> 1552161596      4   a    a
# 3    1 stop <NA> 1552165194      5   a    a
# 8    1 <NA>    a 1552165194      6   a    a
# 4    1 <NA>    b 1552168795      7   b    b
# 9    1 <NA>    b 1552168795      8   b    b
# 5    1 <NA>    a 1552170839      9   a    a
# 10   1 <NA> <NA> 1552170839     10   a <NA>
```

Comment: If I order the `data.frame` I get a different result here: post is equal to "a" for both indexes.

Comment: Not in the sample you provided. Perhaps you can update it and/or use whatever code you have that produces results different than these?

Comment: I did not provide any sample. Your code does not work here because it won't order by timestamp `test[order(timestamp),]` should be `test[order(test$timestamp),]`, otherwise it will throw an error and not sort the df before executing the rest // PS: This is not actually a problem with your code (aside from the ordering problem), I think OPs desired output is just not right for a ordered df.